# How to use Solr's facet for navigation

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm new to Solr's faceting. The facet section in the search response sees only contain facet terms and counts, no documents associated. Now, if I would like to find a document which belongs to a facet, do I need to pass the facet in the search query and do the search over again? what is the best way to use facets? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to issue a new search, typically by adding a filter query, in the form of `myfacetfield:"facetterm"` to your original request.

If you want the documents belonging to each aggregation bucket delivered up front, you can use grouping instead.